# Java: Using Semaphore with timer

Tags: java, timer, semaphore

Hello im trying to synchronize classes using `semaphore.acquire()` and `semaphore.release()`. I'm calling `semaphore.release()` from a class named `ReadSerialPort` and `semaphore.acquire()` from `WriteSerialPort` to connect a phone-center to PC. My problem is that phone-center is not always responding.

I would like to know a way to set timer and make `semaphore.release()` after the time has past.

P.S: I tried using `TimedSemaphore` classes but nothing happened

Comment: would it be an option to put the logic at the acquire side ? there is Semaphore.tryAcquire(timeout)

Comment: The pattern you describe doesn't really make sense. You need to make sure that `release()` is called in a "normal" way, and use timeouts as needed on blocking calls while it's held. (It's really hard to tell how to fix your problems without code and an outline of the shared resources and what's going on with them.)

Comment: Releasing a semaphore on a timer could make things break in a bad way, since I assume there's a reason it has been acquired. What you usually do is try to acquire it with a timeout, and give up if the thread holding the semaphore won't give it back. That way, you'll _know_ something hung and not think it was released in a normal way.

Comment: To rephrase things: if there's a semaphore in your code that never gets released, that is a *bug*, and you need to fix what causes it instead of trying to conceive of a workaround. The fact you're asking about the (bad) workaround also means this question manifests the XY problem and needs to be improved or closed.

Comment: @milimoose : The thing is that im calling Semaphore.acquire to wait till the phone-center will response , where im calling Semaphore.release. The fact is tha phone-center is not always responding so i want to call Semaphore.release() after some time is pass.

Comment: @Jan Goyvaerts : I thought that the solution you game will work and try this semaphore.tryAcquire(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); but its not terminating it.

Comment: As a possibility You may try to use java.util.Timer and TimerTask to release the Semaphore. You  should take care to cancel task when semaphore was release as expected (in time).

Comment: It won't terminate the thread holding the semaphone. But it will timeout the acquire after 10 seconds. Allowing you to run something to signal/fix/... the problem. That's the way it usually works with locking. I'm afraid you'll need to interrupt the holding thread to let it lose its grip. Which it will ignore if it does not forsee that situation.

Comment: @Jan Goyvaerts : You were right and my problem is solved , thanks a lot

Comment: How can i declare that the question is solved?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer of my question was solved by Jan Goynvaeis using semaphore.tryAcquire(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) so the acquire will time out after 10 seconds . After the timeout im using semaphore.release(0) to clear the thread